# Registered plugin for Dynamics 365 that use Azure.Storage.Blobs has stopped working

Tags: c#, plugins, azure-blob-storage, dynamics-365

I have a plugin developed in `Net Framework 4.6.2` that uses the `Azure.Storage.Blobs` nuget package to access a folder inside a container and download its contents.

This plugin is consumed from a cloud flow that has as a trigger "When an HTTP request ir received".

And use an action to call the registered plugin

The used version of `Azure.Storage.Blobs is 12.17.0` and it was working until about 3 weeks ago. Now I am getting this error `Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Storage.Blobs, Version=12.17.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Any reason why this is happening suddenly?

I leave here the content of the csproj file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{EEC7838A-7F97-4D79-9804-E77208AAF255}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Some_Name</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Some_Name</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>Some_Name.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Some_Name.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs">
      <Version>12.17.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies">
      <Version>9.0.2.51</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <Version>13.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Some_Name.snk" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Did you confirm the file is still there?

Comment: yes the file is there

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many variants, downgrading the packages, binding redirect. I also tried to merge the assemblies, a solution that I have chosen on other occasions, for example when I have needed to use `Newtonsoft.Json`.

The merge was the most optimistic option, but it failed to resolve the version of the `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` package.

I have found a workaround, I have changed to the Microsoft packages for integration with the azure blobs `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`, which is deprecated and not supported, but it has given me the time to get my plugin working and plan migrating my code to use the azure storage blobs API Rest.